# How to keep elements on same line with overflow

Tags: html, css, resize, width

I am trying to make a page with some divs aligning horizontally and I want the width to resize based on content so I will get a horizontal scroll if the content is bigger than screen size. I have this:

```
    <div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

the child divs are aligning side by side but when the screen size is reached it breaks into a new line. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would use `white-space: nowrap` along with `display: inline-block`. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/vomecaye/1/edit)**

By the way, try to use CSS instead of inline styles in your HTML. Inline styles should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

```
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row > div {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked for me bu <h2> always forces a new line.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That is because `<h2>` is a block-level element by default.  You should be able to force it inline with custom css.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements